# How to find specific item after collections shuffle?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

OK, my previous thread was not concept very well, so here's another one more precise. I have a quiz with question and 4 possible answers. Questions are from pre populated sqlite database imported in assets folder. I use collections shuffle to place answers randomly to buttons. Now, I have a button for 50/50 help, like i Who wants to become a millionaire, to delete two wrong answers. Here's my problem? How to delete two wrong answers (set their buttons text to "") if I don't know where they are? One of them is right answer. Here's my question code:

```
public void nextQuestion() {

        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();

        try{ 

            mDbHelper.open();

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData(generateWhereClause());
            mAnsweredQuestions.add(c.getLong(0));

            List<Answer> labels = new ArrayList<Answer>();

            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(2), true));
            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(3), false));
            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(4), false));
            labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(5), false));

            Collections.shuffle(labels);

            tacanOdg = c.getString(2);

            if(brojacPogresnihOdgovora < 5){


        question.setText(c.getString(1));

        bOdgovor1.setText(labels.get(0).option);
        bOdgovor1.setTag(labels.get(0));
        bOdgovor1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        bOdgovor2.setText(labels.get(1).option);
        bOdgovor2.setTag(labels.get(1));
        bOdgovor2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        bOdgovor3.setText(labels.get(2).option);
        bOdgovor3.setTag(labels.get(2));
        bOdgovor3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        bOdgovor4.setText(labels.get(3).option);
        bOdgovor4.setTag(labels.get(3));
        bOdgovor4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        netacniOdg.setText("" + brojacPogresnihOdgovora);
        score.setText("Score: " + brojacTacnihOdgovora);
            }

        }
        finally{ 
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
```

Comment: Ok where is your correct answer in the labels list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to sort this thing out, and it's working now! Here's the code.

```
int rnd1, rnd2;

                List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();              

                if (!((Answer)bOdgovor1.getTag()).isCorrect) {
                    list.add(1);
                }
                if (!((Answer)bOdgovor2.getTag()).isCorrect) {
                    list.add(2);
                }
                if (!((Answer)bOdgovor3.getTag()).isCorrect) {
                    list.add(3);
                }
                if (!((Answer)bOdgovor4.getTag()).isCorrect) {
                    list.add(4);
                }   
                Collections.shuffle(list);
                rnd1 = list.get(0);
                rnd2 = list.get(1);

                if ((rnd1 == 1) || (rnd2 == 1)){
                    bOdgovor1.setText("");
                }
                if ((rnd1 == 2) || (rnd2 == 2)){
                    bOdgovor2.setText("");
                }
                if ((rnd1 == 3) || (rnd2 == 3)){
                    bOdgovor3.setText("");
                }
                if ((rnd1 == 4) || (rnd2 == 4)){
                    bOdgovor4.setText("");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact you have two problems to solve: how to know an answer is wrong, and how to randomly delete two wrong answers out of the three? I mean if you always pick the two first wrong answers in display order, you frequently give the solution to the player.

My idea would solve both problems: create at the beginning another list with 2 wrong answers : you may systematically choose c.getString(3) and c.getString(4), as it is before shuffle, it does not matter.

Make this second list available to the fifty/fifty process, and delete the corresponding answers, for example by comparing text.

**Edit**

I just saw something I had not understood. And if I am not wrong, you may forget what I said above, it is in fact much simpler.

- You insert Answers in your list like this: `labels.add(new Answer(c.getString(2), true));`, so I suppose Answer is a class with (at least) 2 attributes. One of them is the text, the other one is a boolean meaning "correct or not ?". i don't know the name of this attribute, but I assume it is named correct for the rest of this explanation
- Then you do `bOdgovor1.setTag(labels.get(0));` so it means you store the Answer object in the button tag.

Thus, there is a way to achieve your goal far simpler than what I said above. To know if an answer is correct, you just have to do:

```
((Answer)bOdgovor1.getTag()).correct
```

For three of the four buttons it will return false, for the correct answer it will return true. So you have your information. Just choose two out of the three answers. Something like:

```
// Get a random number between 1 and 3, 
// it is the number of the wrong answer you will not delete
int rnd = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;

// Init the incorrect answer counter
int i = 0;

// Check the answers. Of course, this code could be factorized in a sub-method
if (!((Answer)bOdgovor1.getTag()).correct) {
  // Incorrect answer
  i++;
  // The (rnd)th incorrect answer will not be deleted, the others will
  if (i != rnd) {
    bOdgovor1.setText("");
  }
}
if (!((Answer)bOdgovor2.getTag()).correct) {
  // Incorrect answer
  i++;
  // The (rnd)th incorrect answer will not be deleted, the others will
  if (i != rnd) {
    bOdgovor2.setText("");
  }
}
if (!((Answer)bOdgovor3.getTag()).correct) {
  // Incorrect answer
  i++;
  // The (rnd)th incorrect answer will not be deleted, the others will
  if (i != rnd) {
    bOdgovor3.setText("");
  }
}
if (!((Answer)bOdgovor4.getTag()).correct) {
  // Incorrect answer
  i++;
  // The (rnd)th incorrect answer will not be deleted, the others will
  if (i != rnd) {
    bOdgovor4.setText("");
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking but I need to setText to "" to two buttons, but I don't where c.getString(3) and c.getString(4) will be to delete them, respectively to setText to "" to those buttons. Can you give an example with some code, my it will work?

Comment: I don't know why but sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. One in 5 or 6 times it doesn't work, it does nothing. I don't know why. I tried some other solution of my own but it never deletes last answer, only two of first three. But yours is good, if only I can figure out why it does not work every time.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is while adding the answers to your list, hold the reference to the Answer object in a variable. Now when you need to refer to the Answer object you can use this reference. In your case, you can make sure that the answers you delete after after 50-50, is not the same as the one you have reference to (i.e. correct answer).

Hope this helps.